# select elements of different columns at different rows of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

```
In [62]: a
Out[62]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Is there an easy way to get [2,3], i.e. the second element of the first row, and the first element of the second row? I have the list of the indices for each row, i.e. [1,0] in this case. I have tried a[:,[1,0]], but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify both i and j for all the elements you want. For example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4]])
i = [0, 1]
j = [1, 0]
print(a[i, j])
# [2, 3]
```

If you need one item from each row, you can use `i = np.arange(a.shape[0])`